# Wall anchors stuck halfway in stucco

Tags: drill, anchor, stucco

I'm trying to install the a security camera outdoor on stucco. I used the drill to drill a hole until it hits something and cannot go further. Then I put the wall anchor into the hole and found that I can only get the wall anchor half inside. I tried to use a hammer but the wall anchor cannot go inside further.

Is it okay for me to cut the wall anchor in half, and then put it into the hole and then screw?

Thanks!

Comment: It is "OK", but it may not hold very well. You need to find out what is blocking your progress - metal studs, metal protecting electrical/plumbing, or something else.

Comment: Thanks! Any advice on how I can find out what's there? It's a small hole and I cannot tell what's there by just peeking at it.

Comment: 1) pull the anchor back out - it's stuck and 1/2 an anchor won't hold the screw it's designed to hold. 2) try taking a picture inside the hole and [edit] it into your post.

Comment: Do you know what the walls are made with, wood, cement?  A simple magnet will show if any steel behind it.

Comment: Respectfully disagree with some folks above. Slice the plastic anchor with a knife, use a shorter screw, install the camera. Give it a tug, and if it stays, you're done. If it falls off, come back and talk.